# Как в Play store узнай стоимость одного показанного рекламного ролика?

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play

Как в Play store узнай стоимость одного показанного рекламного ролика?

Есть ли возможность в аккаунте разработчика либо еще где-то посмотреть стоимость 1 рекламного ролика,который увидел юзер?(допустим длительностью 30 секунд)

Приложение на юнити

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоимость ролика смотрится не в Playe Store - это просто площадка распространения вашей игры. Стоимость смотрится на сайте того сервиса, чью рекламу вы показываете.

И там даже не "стоимость одного просмотра", а "средняя стоимость" будет, т.к. сколько вам дадут зависит и от действий пользователя и от того сколько заплатил тот, чью рекламу у вас показали.